# Python Tkinter pack_forget() incompatible with place() function

Tags: python, tkinter

When using `icon.pack_forget()` with `icon.place()`, the icon label isn't able to hide. I need the label to hide and unhide whenever I like with the position saved

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.title("test")
iconimg = PhotoImage(file="icon.png")
icon = Label(root, image=iconimg)
icon.place(x=20,y=20)
icon.pack_forget()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Bryan Oakley suggested a `place` you can use `place_forget`.
>
> As you suggested the icon label isn't able to hide. I need the label
> to hide and unhide whenever I like with the position saved

Add two buttons one `show()`(unhide) show and `hide()`.

Don't use wildcard `from tkinter import *`

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.title("test")

def hide_widget(widget):
   widget.pack_forget()

 
def show_widget(widget):
   widget.pack()

iconimg = tk.PhotoImage(file="p1.png")
icon = tk.Label(root, image=iconimg)
icon.place(x=20,y=20)
icon.place_forget()

button_hide= tk.Button(root, text= "Hide", command= lambda:hide_widget(icon))
button_hide.pack()

button_show= tk.Button(root, text= "Show", command= lambda:show_widget(icon))
button_show.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yes, `pack_forget` only works with `pack`. For `place` you can use `place_forget`.